# How to make a toast message in a coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

**Setting**

Let's say I have a function that creates a toast message

```
fun makeToast(success: Boolean){
    if (success){
        Toast.makeText(someContext, "Success", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

This function is used in another function that is suspended e.g.

```
suspend fun makeRequest(){
    success = doSomeHTTPRequest()
    makeToast(success)
}
```

When I'm using this function to execute the request I will do it in a coroutine for IO for example i.e.

```
CoroutineScope(IO).launch{
    makeRequest()
}
```

**Issue**

Doing it like proposed above ends in:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

**Question**

What is the best practice to fix this? The straight forward way would be to change `makeToast` to

```
fun makeToast(success: Boolean){
    if (success){
        Looper.prepare()
        Toast.makeText(someContext, "Success", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show()
        Looper.loop()
    }
}
```

However this feels akward since this means that the function `makeToast` already knows that it might not be called in the main thread which creates a weird coupling in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify using the `Main` dispatcher when running code that is only allowed to be called from the main thread. I suppose from the error message it is suggesting you can use other threads if they have a prepared Looper, but it's a lot easier if you simply make Toasts exclusively from the main thread.

Also, a properly composed suspend function should be safe to call from *any* dispatcher. You should never have to specify a Dispatcher to call a suspend function. A dispatcher should be specified when you are calling blocking code and therefore need to specify an appropriate background dispatcher, or when calling a function that is required to be called on the main thread.

So, you can remove `(IO)` from your `launch` call. Specify your dispatchers at the point where the blocking or main-exclusive functions are being called, which is in your `makeRequest` function:

```
suspend fun makeRequest(){
    val success = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { 
        doSomeHTTPRequest()
    }
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        makeToast(success)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

**best way to show Toast message in app
Step 1 create a kotlin class ToastMessage.kt and write code**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.Toast

fun Context.tost(message: String) = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

/*call this method to any class*/

this.tost("successfuly show message")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The question address to not being able to create the toast because of not in the UI thread, this does not explain anything over that, just extracting the statement to a function doesn't solve the problem, also saying "do this and that" does not help in learning and how things work.