# How to show a toast msg on coroutine in composable fun?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

First of all, My english is bad. sorry about that

I wanna show a toast msg like below

but it not working.

'this' should be context but it always CoroutineScope

LocalContext.current not also working

is it bad practice? if yes plz explain and give me good answer!

```
@Composable
fun DogButton() {

    androidx.compose.material.Button(onClick = {

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {

            try {

                val response = ApiAdapter.apiClient.getRandomDogImage()

                if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) // it occur compile error. 


                }

            } catch (exception : Exception) {


            }
        }

    /*TODO*/ }) {

        Text(text = "Get a Dog Image")
    }
}
```

I hope it will be good

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try searching for your question before trying to post it as a new question. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191692/how-to-make-a-toast-message-in-a-coroutine).

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav hey bro, I already saw it but it is not

Comment: my case is about a toast msg on coroutine in 'composable' method bro not related Dispatchers thing

Comment: You can edit the question let everyone know what is the error that you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the LocalContext from your coroutine, since a coroutine `launch` block is not a Composable. Use it before declaring your Button, and get the application Context to be safe, since you're using the context in a coroutine that might outlive the composable.

```
@Composable
fun DogButton() {
    val appContext = LocalContext.applicationContext

    androidx.compose.material.Button(onClick = {
        //...
        Toast.makeText(appContext, ...
```

It is probably more appropriate to do this kind of work in a ViewModel or other similar class for code-organization purposes. You could use an  AndroidViewModel and use its Application reference to get a Context. Then this click listener only needs to call the ViewModel function.

This code:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
```

is usually an antipattern, regardless of whether you're in a Composable. It means you are creating an unconfined coroutine--it will live until completion regardless of whether the associated part of your app is already gone and destroyed, and therefore it is a source of memory leaks and other wasted resources.

Usually, you always start a coroutine using an appropriate CoroutineScope that has a an appropriate lifetime. One that will be cancelled when the work you're launching from it is obsolete.

Possibly, your code is an exception because it isn't interacting with the composable or Activity UI at all. It only launches a Toast, which is a UI at the scope of the application. So if you really want to show this Toast even if the Activity is closed, then it would be OK to launch your coroutine this way.

It is my opinion that in this case, you should use GlobalScope to clearly indicate that this is a coroutine that is not part of a lifecycle that might cancel it. It is effectively the same but you won't be creating a redundant CoroutineScope.

Answer (score 0):

`Composable` functions should not be used to call APIs or do any processing intensive work. ([Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#simple-example)) Your requirement of calling an API and showing a Toast on failure can be handled inside a `ViewModel` and the respective `onClick` of that button.

Comment: The OP's code is not actually in a Composable function. It's in a click listener. There's nothing functionally wrong with starting work in a click listener. Maybe it would make better design sense to move code into another class, but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: thanks guys! I should have considered mvvm